# How to create a function SQL that returns a string from a table?

Tags: sql, function, sql-server-2008-r2

How can I create a function like this?

```
function FN_something (@entrada char(50))

declare @consulta table
declare @notificacao varchar(50)
declare @multa float
declare @saida varchar(50)

set @consulta as = (select num_notificacao,num_multa from table where field = @entrada)
set @notificacao = @consulta.num_notificacao
set @multa = @consulta.num_multa
set @saida = "resultado: "+ @notificacao +";"+@multa

return @saida
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Explain what you want the function to do, including sample data and desired results.  Your pseudo-code doesn't make sense (to me at least).

Comment: I dont know if i make myself clear, but its a simple query with 2 fields, i wanna concat them and return...  (( just like a function in java ))

Comment: Try to avoid declared variables.... In most cases you do not need them...

Comment: and how u build up a function that read a table and concat 2 fields as return ?

Comment: Easy answer: Don't :-D This is *procedural thinking* and is the wrong approach here. Try to find a *set based* solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a function with correct SQL Server syntax:

```
create function FN_something (
    @entrada char(50)  -- should probably be `varchar(50)` rather than `char(50)`
) returns varchar(50)
begin
    declare @saida varchar(50);

    select @saida = 'resultado: ' + num_notificacao + ';' + num_multa
    from table
    where field = @entrada;

    return @saida;
end;
```

Note:  This assumes that the `num_` columns are strings, not numbers.  If they are numbers, you need to convert them or use `concat()`.

EDIT:

A function really isn't appropriate for this.  Probably the best solution is a computed column:

```
alter table t add something as (concat('resultado: ', num_notificacao, ';', num_multa);
```

Then you can get the value directly from the table.  In earlier versions of SQL Server, you would use a view rather than computed column.

Comment: I see, you build up a single field with those 2, and set it right ?

Comment: @NazamuraSenpai . . . It does the work in a single step without the proliferation of local variables.

Comment: Gordon, as far as I see, the issue is a performance problem... Such a function will not solve this as long as the rest is RBAR...

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a function... Scalar functions tend to be a real performance killer. Try to use something like this **inline**

```
SELECT 'resultado: ' 
      + ISNULL(CAST(t.num_notificacao AS VARCHAR(MAX)),'???') 
      + ';' 
      + ISNULL(CAST(t.num_multa AS VARCHAR(MAX)),'???')
FROM SomeTable AS t WHERE t.SomeField=@entrada;
```

If you need a function it was much better to use an *inlined* TVF (syntax without `BEGIN...END` and bind it into your query with `CROSS APPLY`.

### Might be simplified:

If your columns are `NOT NULL` you can go without `ISNULL()`-function. If your columns are strings, you can do without `CAST()`... My code is *defensive* proramming :-D

### Hint

If this is something you need more often, you might introduce a `VIEW` carrying this calculated column and use it instead of your table. You might include this value into your table as computed column as well...

### UPDATE

Great, the *VIEW* you show in the comment is an *inline TVF* actually, which is very good!

My magic crystall ball tells me, that you might need something like this:

```
SELECT cl.*
      ,'resultado: ' + t.num_notificacao + ';' + t.num_multa AS CalculatedResult
FROM dbo.[CampoLivre876]('SomeParameter') AS cl
LEFT JOIN SomeOtherTable AS t ON cl.entrada=t.SomeField --should be only one related row per main row!
```

This will call the iTFV and join it to the other Table, where the two columns are living. I Assume, that the `CampoLivre876`-row knows its `entrada` key.

### Hint 2:

If this works for you, you might include this approach directly into your existing iTVF.

### UPDATE 2

You might try to change your function like here:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[CampoLivre876] () 
RETURNS TABLE
RETURN 
Select cl.mul_numero_notificacao + ';' + CAST(cl.mul_valor_multa as varchar(max)) AS ExistingColumn
      ,'resultado: ' + t.num_notificacao + ';' + CAST(t.num_multa AS varchar(max)) AS CalculatedResult
From Campo_Livre AS cl With(NoLock)
INNER JOIN SomeOtherTable AS t ON cl.entrada=t.SomeField;
```

This should read all lines in one go. Reading 1 row after the other is - in almost all cases - something really, really bad...

Comment: this is what we're trying to avoid, koz its a part of a importing process  ... a 4.000 lines file that call 4.000 the same query.  This part of process does a query and return a recordset where we get 2 fields (notificacao and multa). This query (and its not a query at all, its a view) takes 1 min to run... and the whole process takes 4h to complete.

I've tried to simplify my problem to a single function that read this query and return the fields in a single return.

Comment: @NazamuraSenpai Adding a **scalar** function will make things worse very probably... If ever possible such things should be done inline (if performance matters). Inline means: a view, a computed column, an iTVF or simple code within the query.

Comment: @NazamuraSenpai MIght help to show the view which returns in 1 minute. It might be possible to use an `INNER JOIN` or a `CROSS APPLY` to read the fitting values from your other table using `@entrada` as key for the join operation.

Comment: something like this = ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[CampoLivre876] (@Campo_Livre char(50))
RETURN (
Select Top 1 Campo_Livre.mul_numero_notificacao+';'+CAST(Campo_Livre.mul_valor_multa as varchar)
  From Campo_Livre With(NoLock)Where (Campo_Livre.Campo_Livre = @Campo_Livre)
)

Comment: Where is the value of `@entrada` coming from? Is it part of you table `Campo_Livre`?

Comment: its a string readed from a file, something like   '10075913722437107455', so the function check if this value exists on campo_livre (view) and return 2 fields. otherwise, return null

Comment: @NazamuraSenpai Sorry, did not see the `TOP 1` immediately... If your iTVF reads one row at a time, this seems to be a RBAR approach on its own, which is very bad again... How and from where are you calling this function?

Comment: after uploading a txt file that has 4.000 lines, so the main process read one line at time and search for this TOP1 multa;processo one line after another in a loop that takes 4h to complete. Eventually there are other processing on the routine, but this seems to be the major problem.

Comment: @NazamuraSenpai One more hint: Before you change your function, you might check the naked `SELECT` (adjust table and column names!)